# Algorihtm analysis with time complexity

Tags: algorithms

We know that there are searching algorithms with time complexity O(lgn)

but is there any sorting algorithm with time complexity O(lgn)?

Comment: I mean some of the sorting algorithms like :insertion sort has running time(average case) theta(n2)[n square]

Comment: the average case of merge sort is theta(nlgn)

Comment: the average case of Quick sort is theta(nlogn)  and for bucket sort ,it is theta(n) and for counting sort theta(k+n) etc but I am looking for a sorting algorithm whose running time is O(lgn) which is better than these.[the notation used here is the asymptotic notation]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about statistics, data analysis, or machine learning.

Comment: Sorting implies moving and you cannot move $n$ objects (nor their pointers) in any less than $O(n)$ time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this subproblem: while searching do you have to inspect all the input values? If yes, then how a search algorithm could be sub-linear (less than $O(n)$) when there are $n$ inputs? If not, then how could you sort something without seeing that something?

By the way, I think that this question is not really related with stats exchange, but with other computer science related sites.

Comment: Binary Search is for "Sorted" lists. The complexity is O(lgn).

Comment: Binary search is a searching algorithm, not a sorting algorithm. Your question is if there are "sorting algorithms" with sub-linear time (specifically $O(logn)$). The answer is no.